# share non-renewing in app items subscriptions between multiple ios devices

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

My app is rejected recently from itunes store because of the following reason.

11.6
Content subscriptions using IAP must last a minimum of 7 days and be available to the user from all of their iOS devices

i gone thru the following link
[How to restore non-renewing Apple subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138594/how-to-restore-non-renewing-apple-subscriptions)

but not getting how to share purchased in app item between multiple ios devices. i am using non-renewing in app items.

Any buddy have idea for this. Help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to provide a user with non-renewing subscriptions on all their devices, you must track the purchases on your own server, which means you must also implement a way of identifying individual users, usually by a username and password (separate from their iTunes account credentials).

You should provide an option "create account" and "login" functionality in your app, and prompt the user to save any subscriptions they may have purchased to your server.  Then when they log in on another device, you can restore the transactions.

Apple's restoreCompletedTransactions will not work for non-renewable subscriptions.

Comment: Hello pschwamb , When a user who not register , how do I restore non-renewing subscriptions for his other devices ? thankyou

Comment: But if user Login with different credentials in my app with same itunes purchased id did he received the same purchased subscription or we can force the user to purchase a new subscription with same itunes purchased ID too. Please confirm.

Answer (score -3):

There's a call in `StoreKit`, on the `SKPaymentQueue` called `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]` and it should be able to retrieve previous transactions from iTunes and return them to your application. Using this information you can 'share' previously purchased content on numerous devices.

Comment: The question was for Non-renewable Subscriptions. restoreCompletedTransactions will not work for Non Renewable Subscriptions!